# jQuery - check radio input based on value with space inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is

```
$("input[name=eingangstuer_befestigung][value=ZumEinbetonieren]").prop('checked', true);
```

working and

```
$("input[name=eingangstuer_befestigung][value=Zum Einbetonieren]").prop('checked', true);
```

not?

Is there a way I can keep the spaces in values and still make the damned bugged and time wastig pos called javascript do what it supposed to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your attribute has a space in its value, use single quotes around it, like this:

```
[value='Zum Einbetonieren']
```

Or, if you only need to match the first word, you can use the `~` symbol to match the specified value in a selector that includes white space.  For example:

```
[value~=Zum]
```

The second option would match any selector starting with `Zum`.  (Note the space after the word.)

Comment: Yes this works thanks, it tool me s...load of time figuring out that the damn js don't work because there are spaces in values, I so f..... hate this POS there really need to be an alternative. Thanks for the tip with matching one word :D